# Where are sql server 2012 CLR types installed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've installed [Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) but I can't find where it has been installed.

I'm **specifically looking for** 64bit versions of the following libraries:

- **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll**
- **SqlServerSpatial110.dll**

I've checked `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` but all I see is the following:

[image]

## UPDATE

I've also searched in GAC, windows\system32, and the entire C drive. Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll is not present anywhere on the C drive and I can only find older versions of SqlServerSpatial110.dll. I believe they are older versions because I installed the CLR Types packages today, **9/10/2012** but they have a `last modified` date of `2/11/2012`.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll is in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), SqlServerSpatial110.dll is in the [windows\system32] directory.

Comment: The package is SQLSysClrTypes.msi. If you open it with Orca http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx, you can see the  'ENG_RE_SqlServerSpatial_System_32' component goes in System32 and the 'ENG_RE_Microsoft_SqlServer_Types_GAC_32' component goes in the GAC32 (and the SDK dir).